# any specific example of making a dictionary using logios

Tags: cmusphinx

I followed this [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialdict) trying to build a dictionary, but I think the logios package is generally used for gram and classes file given as input. If I understood it correctly, the dictionary should be built by feeding either a sample text file or a vocabulary file, there shouldn't be any gram file involved. So my questions are

A) Is my understanding about the input correct?

B) Based on above assumption, I guess the correct way of using the package is not building them all, but rather making use of a component inside **Tools** directory named **MakeDict**. But I fell short of any solid example of how to use this tool. So I tried by making modification to **test_MakeDict.sh** file, but it failed with no further information on which component fails. So what shall I do next? Can anyone give any solid command line examples on using this tool, and shall I build the whole package first before I can use any individual component?

The directory layout in MakeDict is as

```
.
├── AUTHORS
├── bin
│   ├── x86-linux
│   │   └── pronounce
│   └── x86-nt
│       ├── libgnurx-0.dll
│       └── pronounce.exe
├── dict
│   ├── command.dic
│   ├── command.txt
│   ├── command.vocab
│   ├── hand.dic
│   └── pronunciation.log
├── lextool.pl
├── lib
│   ├── lexdata
│   │   ├── lexicon.data
│   │   ├── lexicon.key
│   │   ├── ltosru.bin
│   │   ├── nslex.900
│   │   └── nslex.901
│   └── Pronounce.pm
├── logios.log
├── make_pronunciation.pl
├── README
├── test
│   ├── example
│   ├── example.dic.test
│   ├── hand.dict
│   └── pronunciation.log.test
└── test_MakeDict.sh
```

Comment: Its better to use phonetisaurus, not logios

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `pronounce` executable. Depending on your OS you will have to use the linux or nt version.
You can use it as follows:

```
(from the MakeDict root directory)
./bin/x86-linux/pronounce -d [name of the dictionary you want to use from the dict folder] -i [words file] -o [destination dictionary]
```

The words file must be a file contanining the words you want to include in the dictionary, one per line.

The dictionary I used was `cmudict_SPHINX_40`. I don't know which one you should use.